# Android Heap size is smaller than 16mb

Tags: android, size, heap-memory

I am developing an application that takes up about 12MB of heap on a Galaxy Tab 10.1.

When I test this application on my Samsung Vibrant, however, it provides a little more than 3MB of heap and the % of Heap Size Used is at about 98%.

Could someone explain why this is so, and help me figure out a solution?

I know that VMRuntime is deprecated and I haven't been able to discover an alternative to increase my minimum heap size.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All Android Device has different Heap Size for Application.

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mHeapText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mHeapText);

        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        int activityMemory = mActivityManager.getMemoryClass();
        mHeapText.setText("This Device Able to Use for App " + String.valueOf(activityMemory) + "MB");
    }
```

Check your Samsung Vibrant Heap Size.

Comment: The minimum is 16MB. The Vibrant has 48MB.